# How to draw child element's border outside its parent in CSS (or simulate this effect)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not an expert in CSS and trying to customize bootstrap's navbar. There's a parent element with some links inside it. The desired effect - an active link shows a selection highlight below its parent container (a thick black line). When I try to draw a bottom border on the active link, it extends the total height of parent element and border is still drawn inside it. How it can be achieved?

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
 border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: This can probably been done with some height & margin/padding settings.

Comment: `:after`? Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: @GroundZero tried it also, couldn't get it to work. Border is always inside parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a `box-shadow`, e.g.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
   box-shadow: 0 4px 0 #000;
}
```

The box-shadow (with `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes where necessary) applied to an element won't extend the size of the element itself, so its parent element won't grow.

See this example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eHxGz (and note the border of the span element)

Comment: Note that you need to add a `-ms-filter` to support IE8 and lower

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about what you're looking for, but this could be inspiring.

You could use `:after` pseudo-element to create the horizontal line (sort of border) and position it as `absolute` while the list item is positioned as `relative`. (as a reference point for the absolute positioned elements)

```css
li {
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

li > a.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="" class="active">link #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link #3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tijoyigu/2/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Use "override"

Like !important in your css, a example in fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/83y27/5/

```
.parent { 
 width: 310px; 
 height: 650px;
 background: red ;
 background-size:cover;
}

.child {
      position:relative;
      width:700px !important;
      height:512px;
      background: blue !important;
      top:60px;
      bottom:65px;
      left:23px;
      right:24px;
      }
```